# VueJS using parent name tag inside child

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Here is an example:

```
<input name="TESTE" id="TESTE" placeholder="TESTE">
```

is there a way to do that?

```
<div name="TESTE">
    <input :name="parent.name" :id="parent.name" :placeholder="parent.name">
</div>
```

I dont want to do that using vue `data` or components. Can i do that using only pure html like example above?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible. You'll need to use some sort of data field for this to work. Vue renders HTML according to the data you provide it and is otherwise unaware of the properties of surrounding elements. Your best bet is to either hard-code these values or add the appropriate data fields to reference.

It's generally better practice to use the data, anyway, as it will cut down maintenance time and mitigate issues with user error.